# Altering Privatemsg Unread Messages

Tags: drupal-7

I run a full service site that manages different user accounts for multiple clients. I have altered privatemsg so admin users are able to access any of the messages. I had a question about how to show unread messages for each user. The code I have right now only shows the unread messages for the logged in user. The code is below:

```php
$count = privatemsg_unread_count();
if ($count) {
print l( '(' . (int)privatemsg_unread_count() .' new)' , "messages",  array('title' => 'View Inbox')); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass any argument to [privatemsg_unread_count()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_unread_count/7), it will return the number of unread messages for the currently logged-in user. The function accepts an argument, and that is a user object.

If you have a list of user IDs, you can use the following code to get the number of unread messages for each user.

```php
foreach ($uids as $uid) {
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $count = privatemsg_unread_count($account);
  // ...
}
```

If you don't have a list of user IDs, and you are interested in obtaining the number of unread messages for each user, you can use the following code.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->entityCondition('entity_id', 0, '>')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT');

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['user'])) {
  $accounts = user_load_multiple(array_keys($result['user']));

  foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $count = privatemsg_unread_count($account);
    // ...
  }
}
```